# Altering input for HashMap in Java using split() method with array without crashing

Tags: java

working on my current lab and seemed to have run into a slight roadblock. I have never used the split() method up until now and am unsure on how to remedy my problem. Here is a snippet of my code to get started explaining.

```
Map<Integer, Employee> employeeMap = new HashMap<>();
while (true) 
{
    line = scanner.nextLine();
    if (line.startsWith("$")) 
    {
        break;
    }
    String[] employeeTracker = line.split(" ");
    Employee employee = new Employee(
        ++empCount,
        employeeTracker[0],
        employeeTracker[1],
        employeeTracker[2],
        Double.parseDouble(employeeTracker[3]),
        Integer.parseInt(employeeTracker[4]), Boolean.parseBoolean(employeeTracker[5]));
    employeeMap.put(employee.getId(), employee);
 }
```

Original example input: (this was when my Employee employee = new Employee had 4 arguments for input. I have now increased it to 6 for 2 additional inputs needed from a new class being added.

```
John Smith 1234567 10.55
```

New input I'm trying to get to work.

```
*John Smith 1234567 10.55 1 true
```

The issue currently is now that I have made the program accept this new input, I need it to also just work when the old type of input is put in (with just 4 arguments). My first thought is to give some dummy value to those other 2 last arguments when this occurs to prevent crashing, but I have had little luck doing so. Thus, I search for any welcoming suggestions.

Thanks in advance! I would be glad to post any additional code or answer any other questions as necessary.

Comment: a simple condition checking could do the job, like `if(employeeTracker.length == 5)`

Comment: Please also share the code you've tried that did not work and state the error you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the length of the `employeeTracker` array to test what the input is

```
if (employeeTracker.length >= 6) {
     // new inoput
}
else {
    // old input
    // use dummy values
}
```

Comment: Checking the length is also just an **all-around good idea** as a general defense against bad input (**especially** when dealing, as you are, with input provided directly by humans).